# useCallback for function that incorporates batched redux actions (from HOC). What shall i put in the dependancy array?

Tags: reactjs, redux, higher-order-components, usecallback, react-usecallback

I have this component

```
import React from 'react';
import { batch } from 'react-redux';  
  
const ContextMenu = ({
      menuData,
      isOpen,
      changeIsMenuOpen,
      changeAssetType,
    }) => {
      return (
        <ClickAwayListener
          onClickAway={() => {
            batch(() => {
              changeIsMenuOpen(false);
              changeAssetType(null);
            });
          }}
        >
          <ContextMenu
            open={isOpen}
            menuData={menuData}
          />
        </ClickAwayListener>
      );
    };
```

that gets its props from following HOC

```
export default connect(
  state => ({
    isOpen: selectors.getIsMenuOpen(state),
    menuData: selectors.getMenuData(state),
  }),
  {
    changeIsMenuOpen: actions.changeIsMenuOpen,
    changeAssetType: actions.changeAssetType,
  },
)(ContextMenu);
```

I thought it might be a good idea to put onClickAway listener to useCallback, so that its instance wont be recreated in every render. Something like

```
const handleClickAway = useCallback(() => {
    batch(() => {
      changeIsMenuOpen(false);
      changeAssetType(null);
    });
  }, []);
```

but i'm not sure what I must put into the dependency array. Should it be all the methods I am using? Something like

```
[batch, changeIsMenuOpen, changeAssetType]
```

Comment: Hi. Why do you think is it a problem if the function is re-created? This seems like a micro-optimization to me without any real gain to application performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only memoize something when it is actually affecting the application performance.

With that being said, to memoize a function using `useCallback`, you need to pass in all the external items you are using in the function.

So, `[batch, changeIsMenuOpen, changeAssetType]` is a correct dependency array.

`batch` is coming from a library. Also, `changeIsMenuOpen` and `changeAssetType` seem to be redux actions. So, most likely, they are going to be stable. However, one thing to note is that, if you use some object/function from props which is not memoized, then your memoization is essentially useless since the function will be recreated on every render. In fact, as there are additional checks to maintain a memoized function, your application would have performed slightly better without the memoization.

As a rule of thumb, only memoize things, if re-rendering is costly. Make use of the React's Profiler (https://reactjs.org/docs/profiler.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The part about memoization that can do more harm than good, is definately food for thought